# Error While adding an action: #selector() to a bar button item using swift3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uitextfield, selector

I want to create a bar button item on my keyboard that does the same thing as the return key.

I have a function

```
func submitAnswer(_ textField: UITextField)
{//somecode}
```

this function runs every time the return key is pressed shown below.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    submitAnswer(textField)


    //hide keyboard on return
    dismissKeyboard()
    return true
}
```

When i try and add submitAnswer as a bar button action I get an error. 
What am I doing wrong below?

```
func createToolbar(textField : UITextField)
{
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let b = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: "Submit",
        style: .plain,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(submitAnswer(textField))
    )
    toolbar.items = [b]
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}
```

P.S the error I'm getting is: Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer. I tried inserting @objc in front of my submitAnswer function but that didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of your method is `submitAnswer(_:)`, not `submitAnswer(textField)`. But it is simpler just to do `#selector(submitAnswer)`. You don't need to specify the parameters if there is no ambiguity.

However, the signature for a `UIBarButtonItem` action method must be either one with no parameters, or one with a single parameter representing the button.

You can't have a method that takes a text field as the parameter. It must be the bar button item.